# bigquery window function to sum the values within the range of other columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I think i need a window function but it is so specific that i cannot find the answer.

I have a table:

```
datetime             col1  col2  sum_col    start                        end          col_1  col_2
2020-09-21 10:24:40          z    2      2020-09-21 10:24:40     2020-09-22 11:25:10    x      y
2020-09-21 10:24:50          z    2
2020-09-21 10:25:00     x    z    3
2020-09-21 10:25:10     x    z    4
....                   ...  ...   n
2020-09-22 11:24:40     x    y    4
2020-09-22 11:24:50     x    y    4
2020-09-22 11:25:00          y    3
2020-09-22 11:25:10          y    3
```

What I want is to check the values in col_1 & col_2 , and look for them in col1 and col2. I also want to look for them in datetime column within the range of start and end column. In the end, I would like to sum the values in sum_col that fall under the previously explained conditions.

The result would then be:

```
start                        end              col_1     col_2      sum(sum_col)
2020-09-21 10:24:40     2020-09-22 11:25:10     x          y           8+n
```

I hope i'm not asking for to much. I've tried some different approaches which don't work, and with this window function i even don't know where to start.

Comment: Where do you get columns "start", "end", "col_1" and "col_2" from? Or are they just variables that you set?

Comment: yes, this is an imitation of the table I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below my take:

```
with treat_data as (
  select 
    datetime_,
    col1,
    col2,
    sum_col,
    first_value(start_) over (order by datetime_ asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as start_, 
    first_value(end_) over (order by datetime_ asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as end_,
    first_value(col_1) over (order by datetime_ asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as col_1,
    first_value(col_2) over (order by datetime_ asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as col_2
  from
    data_
)
select
  start_,
  end_,
  col_1,
  col_2,
  sum(sum_col) as sum_col
from
  treat_data
where
  col1 = col_1 and
  col2 = col_2 and
  datetime_ between start_ and end_
group by
  1, 2, 3, 4
```

I used FIRST_VALUE() to populate all the nulls on `start`, `end`, `col_1` and `col_2` with the first values shown on the table.

Then, once this is done, it is super easy to follow:

- you set the columns mentioned, plus the sum of the `sum_col` column, and
- use the WHERE clause to state that you only want the sum of those rows where

  - `col1` and `col_1` are equal,
  - `col2` and `col_2` are equal, and
  - `datetime` is between `start` and `end`

Having used the 8 rows that you put as example, **here is the output**:

```
start              | end               |col_1|col_2|sum_col
-------------------+-------------------+-----+-----+-------
2020-09-21T10:24:40|2020-09-22T11:25:10|x    |y    |8
```